# Problema con validación en Javascript

Tags: javascript, validación

estoy comenzando con la validación de formularios en javascript. El ejercicio me pide que se comrpueben que los campos de usuario y contraseña no estén vacíos y que además se compruebe que no le falte el símbolo arroba.

Para ambos casos, debo enviar mensajes distintos.

He llegado hasta el punto de completar la primera situación: si no hay nada escrito en el campo usuario ni contraseña, devuelve el mensaje "Completá tu usuario y contraseña".

Sin embargo, no sé cómo añadir el requisito del @.``

Se me ocurrió lo siguiente:

```
       else if (fname.value !== '@'){
       e.preventDefault();
       para.textContent = 'Añade @ en tu usuario';
    }
 }
```

sin embargo, aunque ponga @, si sumo algun otro caracter igual el error (la alerta) se sigue enviando...

¿sugerencias? Muchas gracias

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
   <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
       <title>ACTIVIDAD 3 JS</title>

   </head>
   <body>

       <form>
           <div>
           <label for="fname">Usuario: </label>
           <input id="fname" type="text">
           </div>
           <div>
           <label for="lname">Contraseña: </label>
           <input id="lname" type="password">
           </div>
           <div>
           <input id="submit" type="submit">
           </div>
       </form>
          <p class="error1"></p>
          script src="control.js"></script>
   </body>
   </html>


   let form = document.querySelector('form');
   let fname = document.getElementById('fname');
   let lname = document.getElementById('lname');
   let submit = document.getElementById('submit');
   let para = document.querySelector('p');

        form.onsubmit = function(e) {
              if (fname.value === '' || lname.value === '') {
              e.preventDefault();
              para.textContent = 'Completá tu usuario y contraseña';
                  }
           }
```

Comment: Revisar la documentación del lenguaje suele ser una buena opción. Por ejemplo [string.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) o `string.indexOf`

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser factible que uses expresiones regulares, en este caso específico del '@' supongo quieres validar sea un email válido, puedes intentar usar lo siguiente:

```
function validarEmail(email) {
  var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
  return regex.test(email) ? true : false;
}
```

Y ya con el `true o false` puedes hacer las validaciones respectivas.

Comment: Gracias! La idea era que el usuario contenga @, como si fuera un usuario de instagram @pepito. Pero muchisimas gracias, me servirá para la próxima

Answer (score 0):

Lo ideal seria que usases pattern en el input (son expresiones regulares para limitar lo que se entra en el campo) y lo mejor seria una validacion a traves de regexp en javascript pero puedes hacer lo que quieres de esta manera:

```js
let form = document.querySelector('form');
  let fname = document.getElementById('fname');
  let lname = document.getElementById('lname');
  let submit = document.getElementById('submit');
  let para = document.querySelector('p');

  form.onsubmit = function (e) {
   if (fname.value === '' || lname.value === '') {
    e.preventDefault();
    para.textContent = 'Completá tu usuario y contraseña';
   }
   if(!fname.value.includes('@'))
   mail.textContent = 'El usuario debe contener @';
  }
```

```html
 <form>
  <div>
   <label for="fname">Usuario: </label>
   <input id="fname" type="text">
  </div>
  <div>
   <label for="lname">Contraseña: </label>
   <input id="lname" type="password">
  </div>
  <div>
   <input id="submit" type="submit">
  </div>
 </form>
 <p class="error1"></p>
 <p id="mail"></p>
```

Lo que hace es constatar que el value contenga (includes) un @ entre sus caracteres

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta Hernan